# Unable to generate code created by Dagger in Kotlin Android App

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, dagger-2

Thanks for reading, After some issues with Annotations after converting a Java App to Kotlin I have added the modules components qualifiers and Scopes and it builds after rebuilding it.But I'm stuck here as I want to use the DaggerFragmentComponent (Fragment Component) but it doesn't import as in it hasn't created that after rebuilding.

I only have access to DaggerCollections which is not want I want to execute the dependency injection....

FragmentModule:

```
package com.example.daggerappkotlin.di.module

import com.example.daggerappkotlin.di.qualifier.FragContext
import com.example.daggerappkotlin.ui.HomeFragment
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides

@Module
class FragmentModule(internal var fragment: HomeFragment) {

    @FragContext
    @Provides
    internal fun provideFragment(): HomeFragment {
        return fragment
    }


    @FragContext
    @Provides
    internal fun provideConnection(): String {
        return "Connected Ben Mohammad"
    }
}
```

FragmentComponent:

```
package com.example.daggerappkotlin.di.component

import android.content.Context
import com.example.daggerappkotlin.di.module.FragmentModule
import com.example.daggerappkotlin.di.qualifier.ApplicationContext
import com.example.daggerappkotlin.di.scope.FragmentScope
import com.example.daggerappkotlin.ui.HomeFragment

import dagger.Component

@FragmentScope
@Component(dependencies = [ApplicationComponent::class], modules = [FragmentModule::class])
interface FragmentComponent {

    @ApplicationContext
    val context: Context

    fun inject(frag: HomeFragment)


}
```

ApplicationModule:

```
package com.example.daggerappkotlin.di.module

import android.content.Context
import com.example.daggerappkotlin.MyApplication
import com.example.daggerappkotlin.di.qualifier.ApplicationContext
import com.example.daggerappkotlin.di.qualifier.DatabaseInfo
import com.example.daggerappkotlin.di.qualifier.NetworkInfo
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides

@Module
class ApplicationModule(val application: MyApplication) {

    @ApplicationContext
    @Provides
    internal fun provideContext(): Context {
        return application
    }

    @Provides
    @DatabaseInfo
    internal fun provideDatabaseName(): String {
        return "dummy_db"
    }

    @Provides
    @DatabaseInfo
    internal fun provideDatabaseVersion(): Int? {
        return 1
    }

    @Provides
    @NetworkInfo
    internal fun provideApiKey(): String {
        return "SOME_API_KEY"
    }
}
```

ApplicationComponent:

```
package com.example.daggerappkotlin.di.component

import android.content.Context
import com.example.daggerappkotlin.MyApplication
import com.example.daggerappkotlin.data.local.DatabaseService
import com.example.daggerappkotlin.data.remote.NetworkService
import com.example.daggerappkotlin.di.module.ApplicationModule
import com.example.daggerappkotlin.di.qualifier.ApplicationContext
import dagger.Component
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ApplicationModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent {

    fun inject(application: MyApplication)

    @ApplicationContext
    val context: Context

    val networkService: NetworkService

    val databaseService: DatabaseService



}
```

I am trying to do the building in MainActivity, HomeFragment and the MyApplication....

[GithubRepo](https://github.com/BenMohammad/DaggerAppKotlin)

[image: MainActivity Issue]

Comment: Please check your build log and include the Dagger errors in your question

Comment: Why `internal`? And what are your actual build errors that prevent the component from being generated? Maybe you forgot `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`?

Comment: Yes, I forgot the kotlin-kapt, works fine now.Thanks